# What is the minimum exposure to a virus to acheive immunization?

Tags: immune-system, virus, disease

Is it possible to gain immunity against a virus if the exposure to the virus is not large enough to cause any clinical symptoms? And if so, would the immunity achieved without symptoms be as strong as immunity achieved by going through the full progression of the disease? (ex: chicken pox and measles)? ... If so, would the optimal exposure to a given virus be as large as possible, but not large enough for the incubation to take full effect, and so avoid any clinical symptoms, whilst still gaining immunity? thanks...

Comment: In order to generate an immunity to a virus, there has to be enough of an infection to generate an immune response. By this I mean that the infection has to get past our body's first line of defense, the white blood cells, and cause the immune system to send out t-helper cells to get antigen markers on the virus' protein shell, which in turn the body uses to make specific antibodies for the virus in question. I don't know that this is quantifiable, which is why I offer this as a comment rather than an answer.